# How to get the last position when drag/drop cursor mouse out canvas

Tags: wpf

In WPF, I dont still get the last position when my cursor drag/drop out of canvas. 
Please tell me the solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the last position with `MouseMouve` event. If you still want to get the `MousePosition` even the mouse is not on the `canvas` anymore, then you have to subscripe the `MouseMove` `event` from the parent `control/window`.

Comment: How to know the cursor out of canvas or rectangle ?

Comment: For example the `MouseLeave` event. (https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.mouseleave?view=netframework-4.7.1)

Comment: Do you want to know the position the mouse is in as it leaves the canvas?

Comment: This seems a bit odd. What are you going to do with this data?